# Merge two planes with texture into one mesh

Tags: three.js

I want to merge two meshes in threejs. I want to create a geometry of two planes that are intersecting each other perpendicular. Both of the planes must have the same texture. 
I've tried the following.

Currently this error occurs: THREE.Geometry.merge(): geometry not an instance of THREE.Geometry.

```
  var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/img/foo.png');
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide, transparent: true });
var m_plane_1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 128, 128); 
var m_plane_2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(128, 128);
var plane_1 = new THREE.Mesh(m_plane_1, material);
var plane_2 = new THREE.Mesh(m_plane_2, material);
plane_2.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2;

var combined =   new THREE.Geometry();

combined.merge(plane_1); // does not work 
//combined.merge(plane_1.geometry, plane_1.matrix); // this does not work
//combined.merge(m_plane_1.geometry, m_plane_1.matrix); // this does not work

scene.add(combined);
```

I've tried to read the source code for merge() but could not come to any conclusion. I've read stackoverflow threads but their approach does not work for me. 
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the intersection of the geometries. Then you can apply whatever texture you want to that new geometry.

To get the intersection, you should use Chandler Prall's Constructive Solid Geometry code: http://evanw.github.io/csg.js/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to merge two geometries, but probably the simplest way to achieve what you want is to use the following pattern:

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 128, 128 );
var geometry2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 128, 128 );
geometry2.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY( Math.PI / 2 ) );
geometry.merge( geometry2 );
```

three.js r.69

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
plane_1.updateMatrix();
//Now the function merge
combined.merge(plane_1.geometry, plane_1.matrix);


//combined.merge(plane_1); // does not work
//combined.merge(plane_1.geometry, plane_1.matrix); // this does not work
//combined.merge(m_plane_1.geometry, m_plane_1.matrix); // this does not work
```